# How can change hard disk name (not partition)

Tags: hard-drive, macos

The title is self-explained: I want to change the hard disk name (not the partition). I am not able to do it with Disk Utility. Any solutions?

I'm on Yosemite

Comment: I'd like to see a picture attached to the question, similar to klanomath's, but showing the entire Disk Utility window so we can see format type etc. I've never seen a drive that cannot identify itself... but many partitions called UNTITLED (especially if they're FAT/NTFS)

Answer (score 4):

The device name is probably hard coded into the `PCB` or soft coded into the `Service Area` of the platter (aka hard drive firmware) and might be changed by the manufacturer but not by the customer.

[image]

The partition name (green) might be changed easily, the device name (red) not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was asking that because the hard disk I installed (Samsung SSD 850 PRO) has not that name but it's called "Untitled"! It's horrible. Then I can't change it? Is it normal that the SSD is called Untitled?

Comment: @fred k I'm searching for a better answer. Maybe it's working like that: the firmware provides some (fixed) hex values for size, manufacturer, product number etc. and one **editable** file in the depth of the system contains human readable transliterations where your disk might be added.

Answer (score 1):

Try `diskutil cs rename lvgUUID "newName"`. You will need a lvgUUID(Logical Volume Group): `diskutil cs list`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why or how the physical name of the disk would be enmeshed with the core storage volumes (if any) on that drive?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `Finder > Preferences > General`, mark `Show hard disks` it appears on the desktop, then select it with single left click and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I was asking for the hard disk, not the partition

Comment: that **is** the hard disk, you can't give a partition a name as the user never sees it.

Comment: ermm... no - that's the partition. That's *all* the user usually sees.

Answer (score -1):

Easy Fix 
Go to System Preferences - User and Groups, Righthand click on Admin User this will open advanced options, account name and Full name can be changed from there!!

Answer (score -3):

want to know how?
Connect it to a windows computer.
Press rename.
Done

Comment: Same result as changing the Volume name on a Mac, it doesn't change the device name, which is hard-coded